# create form inside php script

Tags: php, html

I have a table and use the following to create a button inside one of the cells:

```
print("<td> <input type=\"submit\" name=\"toedit\" value=\"Submit\" >
    <form action=\"Manage_Customer_Information_refined_list.php\" method=\"post\">
        <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"Submit\" name =\"submit_button\" >
    </form>
</td>");
```

When i go to call upon the button (press it) using

```
if(print_r($_POST["\"submit_button\""]))
{
    print "button pressed";
}
```

It says

> undefined index "submit_button"

Please Help :/

Comment: There are so many things wrong here. But lets stick to the obvious. `print_r` is a function with highly mixed return values, it can return a bool, a string, an int, a float, god knows what, it depends on the context. However, to keep this simple, `print_r` doesn't belong in that `if`. It should be something like this `if(isset($_POST['submit_button']))`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
print("<td> 
    <form action=\"Manage_Customer_Information_refined_list.php\" method=\"post\">
        <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"Submit\" name =\"submit_button\" >
        <input type=\"submit\" name=\"toedit\" value=\"Submit\" >
    </form>
</td>");
```

and if you want to submit on same page then remove `Manage_Customer_Information_refined_list.php` form form.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"Submit\" name =\"submit_button\" >
```

to

```
<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" name =\"submit_button\" >
```

Remove

```
<input type=\"submit\" name=\"toedit\" value=\"Submit\" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your condition to this

```
if(isset($_POST["submit_button"]))
{
   print "button pressed";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you write `<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"Submit\" name =\"submit_button\" >` will be evaluated to `... name="submit_button"` which means you should access this input value from the server side using $_POST["submit_button"].

The way you did write `$_POST["\"submit_button\""]` expect the input field to be written as `<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"Submit\" name =\"\"submit_button\"\" >` and i don't think that this is a valid syntax, also you should put the submit button inside the form not outside of it.